# Resource limitation for Bamboo local agents

Tags: linux, ubuntu, continuous-integration, bamboo

Is it possible to set memory/CPU limits for specific Bamboo local agent? It's disappointing when memory leak in any plan causes oom kill of Bamboo Server itself. We have dozens of plans by different teams and it's impossible to take care of every plan manually.

My environment:
Ubuntu 22.04
Bamboo Server 9.2.3